# Objective-C : Passing data between classes and making the data accessible from other classes

Tags: ios, objective-c

I'm new here and new to iOs programming too. 
I'm creating a math app. My app now has some viewcontrollers which perform different calculation, and I want to save results from each viewcontroller to a new viewcontroller(ResultViewController) and make the saved data accessible from another viewcontroller.

I've read 
[Passing Data between View Controllers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5210535/passing-data-between-view-controllers)
and tried to push data to a navigating stack but ended up with "Could not load NIB in bundle".

```
ResultViewController *resultVC = [[ResultViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"ResultViewController" bundle:nil];
resultVC.resultString = msg;
[self.navigationController pushViewController:resultVC animated:YES];
```

Besides I'm not sure whether this can make the saved data accessible from the other classes??

Another problem I'm facing is when we access a viewcontroller and go back to the same page, all data in the same page will be reset(I want to keep the data). So should I leave the ResultViewController and change to another object?? Or do you know other methods for this??

Thank you and excuse me for my English. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would highly recommend to read [WorkingwithObjects - Developer.Apple](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/cocoa/conceptual/programmingwithobjectivec/WorkingwithObjects/WorkingwithObjects.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40011210-CH4-SW1) and [communication-patterns](http://www.objc.io/issue-7/communication-patterns.html) instead of 'Passing Data between View Controllers' before you start.

Tryout the examples and identify some best-practice recommendations regarding when you should use which mechanism.

> Could not load NIB in bundle

The error means that there is no .xib file with the name `ResultViewController`. Cross check the .xib file name again. Also look at the `Target -> Buid Phases -> Copy Bundle Resources` to see the .xib file is in red colour.